# Azure API app sample works for a while then dies

Tags: azure-web-app-service

Thought I would try my hand at Azure App Services with an Azure API App. I started with this tutorial:

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-dotnet-create-api-app/

Worked great last night after I published. Come back this morning to keep going through the tutorial and the API url is dead. I am clicking the API URL from inside Azure portal and I am logged in.

I followed the tutorial and set the access level for the API to "Available to Anyone".

I get: "Sorry, but we’re having trouble signing you in. We received a bad request."

Only other info I get is:
AADSTS50011: The reply address '...' does not match the reply addresses configured for the application: ...

[image: Azure API Error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the post below Application Insights are not yet supported with Azure API Apps.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/96eeb06c-8157-4a4f-9d3a-4fa3eced5c55/authentication-failure-on-new-api-app-even-though-authentication-is-disabled?forum=AzureAPIApps

When creating a new API app for Azure App Services be sure Application Insights is NOT checked/enabled for the project.

[image]